# How to make manipulatable number grid in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix

I want to make a number grid in Ruby that gives outputs like this (not exactly, but close):

```
0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   ------------------ 
1 |
2 |
3 |
4 |
5 |
6 |
```

where the spaces (coordinate points) are filled in with random numbers. I also need it to be manipulatable (e.g. I can easily find the value of a point given it's coordinates and also change it). I've been trying to use arrays for this but haven't yet found a nice way to get it together. How can I do this in an efficient manner using Ruby?

Thank you so much!

UPDATE: I have an array like this:

```
 $array = [

        # 0    1    2    3   4    5     6   7    8
        ['O', '-',' -','-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], #0
         ['|', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], #1
         ['|', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], #2
         ['|', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], #3


         ]
```

How can I display it in a friendly-for-eyes way?

Comment: Check out the [Matrix class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) perhaps?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying that now... Still need some help though

Comment: What are your rules for generating random numbers? For example do you want a random number between 0 - 9? And would each row allow the same number appearing more than once? So is a row like [1,1,3,2,9,4,8,6,6,] allowed?

Comment: Repeating numbers are allowed. I don't actually mean to generate random numbers; I have a set of numbers that go in there. I just need a way to find a friendly way to visualize this in a CLI and also to be able to manipulate it (e.g. array[x][y]=3 turns the (x,y) point on the array to 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay try this (see edits for previous answers, but this one is the best I feel):

```
grid = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
         [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1],
         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5] ]

#prints first row and dashed line
r1 = grid[0]
f1 = grid[0][0]
print f1
print "   "
r1.shift
print r1.join(" ")
r1.unshift(f1)
puts ""
puts "   ------------------"

#Prints all other rows
grid.shift
grid.each do |r| 

        f = r[0]
        print f
        print " | "
        r.shift
        print r.join(" ")
        r.unshift(f)
        puts
end
```

Output:

```
0   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   ------------------
1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
2 | 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
3 | 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
4 | 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
5 | 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
6 | 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Changed my answer, take a look.

Comment: Mixing formatting with data? Storing actual data in a string instead of array? This can/should be done in a better way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I listened and you made good points... so I completely changed my answer. Better?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: yes, quite a bit. I retracted my DV :)

Comment: It seems great in theory, but for some reason(s) it didn't work for me. For example: it gave an ArgumentError for the second-to-last line implying that "puts" needed 1 argument instead of 0. And perhaps you have one too many commas in the end of the array? Thank you for your suggestions though!

Comment: The comma was superfluous but harmless to the code, I will remove thanks! When are you getting the error? It runs as it is fine, so does it fail after you've modified some part?

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you too late, it turns out I made a modification error. It works great! Thanks! @sagarpandya82