# How to print multidimensional array row by row

Tags: arrays, ruby

Maybe the title is misleading, but that's the best way I can word it. I have a multidimensional array:

```
arr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0]
]
```

How would I get the outcome to print exactly like so:

```
00

00

00

00
```

Would `.join` work?

Comment: Yes `join` will work if you try it.  Now, go and try  it - if you have issues, ask a question.  There have been no news yet where Ruby interpreter attacked someone for writing code that did not work at first try.

Comment: yeah, play around with `irb` or `pry` before asking would be the best habit

Comment: you may find this [question and answer useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596397/how-to-make-manipulatable-number-grid-in-ruby/33597588#33597588)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421.

Comment: Firstly, I tried many variations and I couldn't get it to work. Secondly, in my search I couldn't find a way to make this work. Thirdly, I'm about as new to ruby (programming, in general, too) as it gets (seriously, I've been doing this for about three weeks). So, with that being said, I tried .join, thinking I was on the right path, so maybe my question "Would .join work?" was misleading. It should say "Why doesn't .join work?" Anyway, with the help of the two answers below I figured it out and my code is actually not a carbon copy of theirs, only very similar and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
> a = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
> puts a.map(&:join)
00
00
00
=> nil
```

if just you want the exact result (two newlines in between)

```
a.map(&:join).join("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` for your array, and you will have this output.

```
arr.join
# => "00000000"
```

Or if you whant to "split" the sub array you can use this join

```
arr = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
arr.map(&:join).join("\n")
# => "00\n00\n00\n00"
```